# How does Go allocate memory when using new(string)

Tags: go

Consider the following code:

```
    str := new(string)
    p := str
    fmt.Printf("Current value = %v %p\n", *str, str)
    *str = "abc"
    fmt.Printf("New value = %v %p\n", *str, str)
    fmt.Printf("Current value = %v %p\n", *p, p)
```

In the second line, `p := str` both pointers point to the same location, the memory address where `new(string)` allocated the default value of a string, an empty string. I would have expected `*str = "abc"` to be a problematic assignment (in c for example, this could overwrite memory). But not only does this work and p take on the same value, it also seems to continue to work if I set *str to be some very large string.

I would expect that str is pointing to a location that has a fixed number of bytes allocated to it. For a default string value, that seems to be 16 bytes. How does golang allow the assignment of some arbitrarily sized string to the location of a pointer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question at all, this is how pointers work. Can you clarify what the confusion is, or what you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Oh, maybe the question is about how strings are fundamentally represented? Go strings are not null delimited arrays like in C, they are represented by a struct with a pointer and a length.

Comment: Ah, so it is the struct's pointer that gets moved around and that also explains the 16 bytes at *str.

Comment: No, the struct is immutable, you just overwrote the struct. The fact that you can assign the value at all means it is the same size.

Comment: Is it immutable if you overwrote the struct at the exact location? What is the difference between overwriting the struct vs changing the struct's pointer and size value? If it is truly immutable, you would create a new struct elsewhere and change the string pointer to point to that.

Comment: Yes, it is immutable as far as the language is concerned. Overwriting the struct through a pointer is discarding the old value and writing a new value in its place. You cannot (without `unsafe`) directly write to the length or data pointer individually.

Comment: `string` internally is just a struct. The string itself is held in a byte slice within that struct. The struct size never changes, but the byte slice can be replaced with a slice of different length. Allocating the `string` has nothing to do with allocating the byte slice.

Answer (score 3):

> In the second line, p := str both pointers point to the same location, the memory address where new(string) allocated the default value of a string, an empty string.

Correct

> I would have expected *str = "abc" to be a problematic assignment (in c for example, this could overwrite memory). But not only does this work and p take on the same value, it also seems to continue to work if I set *str to be some very large string.

Your expectation is just plain wrong. Go is not C and strings are represented differently in Go than in C.

> I would expect that str is pointing to a location that has a fixed number of bytes allocated to it.

Thats true. Any type has some defined fixed size. This is a feature of Go.

> For a default string value, that seems to be 16 bytes.

No. 1. This the size of the string variable is not dependent on the string content (also see above). 2. This is platform dependent. 3. Yes 16 bytes = 2 words on 64bit systems.

> How does golang allow the assignment of some arbitrarily sized string to the location of a pointer?

A variable of type `string` doesn't hold the actual string content, it is just a 2 word descriptor, roughly (length, pointer-to-actual-content). `*str = "abc"` doesn't store "abc" in the string variable: It stores "abc" somewhere and make the pointer-to-actual-content point there. The type `string` in Go is not what a `char*` is in C.